# of_node_name_eq for device tree node label

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, yocto, xilinx, device-tree

I am trying to read the label from my devices, but I keep reading `pid@43c00000` instead of `pid_0` when I use `->full_name` on a `struct device_node *`. Is there a method to reading the label, or do I need to change the device tree entry of the node name to look something like `pid0@43c00000` for `pid_0`.

```dts
                pid_0: pid@43c00000 {
                        clock-names = "s00_axi_aclk";
                        clocks = <&clkc 15>;
                        compatible = "xlnx,pid-1.0";
                        reg = <0x43c00000 0x10000>;
                        xlnx,adc-width = <0xc>;
                        xlnx,integrator-cycles = <0x186a0>;
                        xlnx,op-width = <0x13>;
                        xlnx,q = <0x6>;
                        xlnx,s00-axi-addr-width = <0x5>;
                        xlnx,s00-axi-data-width = <0x20>;
                };
                pid_1: pid@43c10000 {
                        clock-names = "s00_axi_aclk";
                        clocks = <&clkc 15>;
                        compatible = "xlnx,pid-1.0";
                        reg = <0x43c10000 0x10000>;
                        xlnx,adc-width = <0xc>;
                        xlnx,integrator-cycles = <0xa>;
                        xlnx,op-width = <0x13>;
                        xlnx,q = <0x6>;
                        xlnx,s00-axi-addr-width = <0x5>;
                        xlnx,s00-axi-data-width = <0x20>;
                };
```

Comment: Perhaps you could define an alias as a property in the `/aliases` node, for example: `pid_0 = &pid_0;`. If the path string passed to the `of_find_node_by_path()` and `of_find_node_opts_by_path()` functions does not begin with a `/`, the first component of the path will be looked up as a property in the `/aliases` node and replaced with the property value. For example, `node = of_find_node_by_path("pid_0");`.

Comment: Could you explain why you need the label? If the driver for `xnlx,pid-1.0` devices should treat the device differently depending on which device it is, then the devices should have different `compatible` string properties. The `compatible` property can contain several strings ordered from most specific to most generic.

Comment: @IanAbbott thank you for the fantastic advice! Once my HDL design is done being prototyped, I think this will not be an issue since you're right that 
`If the driver for xnlx,pid-1.0 devices should treat the device differently depending on which device it is, then the devices should have different compatible string properties.`

Comment: @IanAbbott The reason I want the label now is so that I can create a character device with the name `/dev/pid_0` that actually corresponds to the label `pid_0`. I settled on [making the character device files look like this](https://gitlab.ssec.wisc.edu/nextgenshis/yocto/poky/-/blob/pid-dev/meta-pid/recipes-modules/pid-mod/files/pid.c#L184) `/dev/43c00000.pid` and `/dev/43c10000.pid` just so I know which device I'm using since they have different properties like `integrator-cycles`

Comment: Please see a correction to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a method to reading the label

No, there is no "*method to reading the label*" from the `struct device_node` because labels are not saved in that data structure.
From section 6.2 of the DeviceTree Specification, v0.4-rc1:

```
Labels are only used in the devicetree source format and are not encoded into the DTB binary
```

Your driver at runtime only has access to the DTB, so there are no labels.

---

> I keep reading `pid@43c00000` instead of `pid_0` when I use `->full_name` on a `struct device_node *`.

Simply because `pid@43c00000` is the (full) name of that node.
`pid_0` is the label, and should not be confused with the node name.

Note that you can also review the contents of the DTB at **/proc/device-tree**, where nodes are (sub)directories and properties are files.

---

**ADDENDUM: CORRECTION**

Contrary to the cited DeviceTree Specification, there does seems to be a way to save the labels from the dts during compilation. This label capability is used by the DT overlay handler in the kernel.
The [Devicetree Overlay Notes](https://docs.kernel.org/devicetree/overlay-notes.html) mentions:

```
If the base DT was not compiled with the -@ option then the "&ocp" label 
will not be available to resolve the overlay node(s) to the proper 
location in the base DT.
```

A *gotcha* is that not every version of the **dtc** supports this -@ flag.
One [man page](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dtc&sektion=1) describes this -@ option as:

```
    -@       Emit a __symbols__ node to allow plugins to be loaded.
```

This suggests that a second *gotcha* may be that the label you want to use will not be contained in the device_node structure passed to the driver.